# Why does end-of-line operator ($) not work in MariaDB unless I include a trailing null?

Tags: mariadb, pcre

This is the field of interest:

```
something    VARCHAR(8)          NULL,
```

It can contain non-digits, but I need to select for rows that contain only digits in this field. I have tried to use this regular expression:

```
something RLIKE '^\\d+$'
```

This fails to match. However, if I add a Kleene closure for null bytes at the end, it matches. This is the expression that matches:

```
something RLIKE '^\\d+\x00*$'
```

My question is: **am I doing something wrong?** Is there a flag I should have set? I don't see this mentioned in the documentation anywhere. MariaDB's documentation does not mention padding `VARCHAR`s with null bytes. In fact, a section in their documentation leaves me with the impression that my first regular expression should have worked. Here is a quote from the documentation:

> This example checks if the string consists of "word" characters only:

```
SELECT 'abc' RLIKE '^\\w+$';
-> 1
```

Comment: `SELECT HEX(something) ...` so we can see whether there is a zero-byte.

Comment: `VARCHAR` is implemented with a length field, followed by the bytes in the string.  It does not use a zero-byte at then end for termination.  However, it _may_ be possuble for you to put such in the string.

Comment: `SELECT HEX (code) FROM UnitedNationsM49Subregions;` gives me `303632`, for instance.

Comment: Wait a second, this works all of a sudden on my Mac. The failure was on my Windows machine. Could this have to do with line endings?

Comment: Actually, that still doesn't explain why adding the Kleene closure for the null byte worked...

Comment: `303632` is `062`, no nulls or zero bytes (just a zero character).

Comment: Obselete code for South-central Asia?

Comment: Astute observation, @RickJames, but I have a column in my table for indicating which are obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give version or code samples, but the following works in MariaDB 10.3.9 with default settings:

```
CREATE TABLE r (x VARCHAR(8) NULL);
INSERT INTO r VALUES ('abc'),('123'),('1d3');

SELECT x RLIKE '^\\d+$' FROM r;
+------------------+
| x RLIKE '^\\d+$' |
+------------------+
|                0 |
|                1 |
|                0 |
+------------------+
```

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#default_regex_flags has some behavior flags, but I don't know if this is relevant to your case.